# How to view data "$content" in HTML using JS

Tags: javascript

I want to display the data coming to the "table" in HTML, but I can't understand what's wrong

```
function renderUI(table) {
    $content = '<div><table>'

    table.forEach((row, index) => {
        $content = `<tr>
            <td>${index}</td>
            ${ row.forEach((innerRow, index2) => {
                return `<td>${innerRow.time}</td> <td>${innerRow.route}</td>`
            }) }
        </tr>`
    });

    $content += '</table></div>'

    $('#app').append($content);
```

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong? What issue are you experiencing?

Comment: `$content = \`<tr>…\` - you are _overwriting_ the variable here in each loop iteration.

Comment: You need to use **`$content += <tr> .....`** or else it will not append new text.

Comment: Have you tried using `.html($content)` ?

Comment: it should output the data in HTML,bat it only creates an empty table. logs show that data is coming but not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem 1

```
$content = `<tr>
```

That's an assignment, not an append. You got it right on the penultimate line. You need to change it in the middle too.

## Problem 2

```
${ row.forEach((innerRow, index2) => {  … return
```

Returning from `forEach` doesn't do anything. `forEach` **always** returns `undefined`.

You need to use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead. That will return an array which you can call `.join("\n")` on to give you a string containing all the chunks of HTML you generate